# Can we express 24/35 into any 2 real factors except 1.0 and 0.6857142857142857 that has less than 4 decimal spaces (no round-off allowed)

Tags: real-numbers, fractions

Question says it all. I need to convert 24/35 (or 0.6857142857142857) into 2 factors of that don't have so many decimal places (real number with lesser decimal places) and no rounding-off is allowed. It is required for a physics experiment. Any help is appreciated.

I tried a few like:

```
 0.5x = 0.6857142857142857
```

So,

```
x = 0.6857142857142857/0.5
```

but the result

```
 (1.371428571428571)
```

still has 15 decimal places (same amount of decimal places as the original number)

**Edit:**

I'm sorry. I didn't know that it is a non-terminating decimal expansion.
However, considering 0.6857142857142857 as the number to be factorized, is it possible to find 2 numbers that can be multiplied to get this number?

I thought its a terminating expansion because I was getting incorrect results for the experiment when I input 0.685714286 instead of 0.6857142857142857

**Edit 2:**

Link to the experiment: http://vlabs.iitb.ac.in/bootcamp/labs/ic/exp9/exp/simulation.php

(there are 2 embedded simulations on this page, my experiment is the first one)

Here, Ra*C = 24/35 and Rb = 10*Ra and Ra >= 10 and V can be anything, doesn't matter

So, I took these values:

```
 Ra = 68.57142857142857 
 Rb = 685.7142857142857 
 C = 0.01
```

and I got the correct output (i.e. Fout = 0.1 exactly)

If I reduce it to the values:

```
 Ra = 68.57142857 
 Rb = 685.7142857 
 C = 0.01
```

then it is approximately equal to 0.1 but not exactly (as you can see in the experiment)

Is it possible to get 0.1 as Fout with a lesser decimal places?

Comment: You know that $24/35$ isn’t exactly equal to $0.6857142857142857$, right? The decimal expansion is infinite.

Comment: $\frac{24}{35}$ has a nonterminating decimal expansion and is equal to $0.6\overline{857142}$. If you want, try $\frac{1}{7}x = \frac{24}{35}$.

Comment: What about $$0.5944305\cdot 0.1153565111$$ for your few decimal factors

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9999221/double-precision-decimal-places for the (likely) explanation of why you are seeing 15 decimal places.

Answer (score 3):

If you write $\frac{24}{35}$ as the product of two fractions with smaller denominators, one will have denominator $5$ and the other denominator $7$.  Since $\frac17$ is a repeating decimal with period $6$, you cannot get down to $4$ decimal places.

I don't really understand what you mean by "no roundoff allowed", though.  $\frac{24}{35}$ has a repeating decimal representation, so you've already rounded it off.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I didnt know that it is a non-terminating decimal expansion. However, considering 0.6857142857142857 as the number to be factorized, is it possible to find 2 numbers that can be multiplied to get this number? I thought its a terminating expansion because I was getting incorrect values for the experiment when I put 0.685714286 instead of 0.6857142857142857

Comment: Well you won't get $15$ decimal places by multiplying two $4$-digit decimals, surely.

Comment: @unknown Since this sounds like there is a computer involved in some way, you should also realize that the value you enter is most likely stored internally in a base-2 floating point format. In that format, even some terminating decimals like $0.2$ have a non-terminating binary expansion. If you really need precision higher than what the hardware supports then one recourse is to work with exact fractions, instead of floating points. That carries certain overhead, however, so the first thing to check is that you really need that kind of precision.

Comment: @dxiv I have put the reference in the question. You can check it out. And yes, there is computer involved, but in a different way

Comment: @unknown Only you can judge the precision you require in a given calculation. A popular post on SO about the pitfalls is [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) with relevant information and links.

Comment: ok, thanks @dxiv